# Display text without markdown syntax in Django

Tags: python, django, markdown

Is it possible to display just text without the markdown syntax with Django?

If a user adds some text with `markdown` syntax and if I don't call markdown in my template ({{some_text}}) I get something like this:

```
**this is a test** _with markdown_ `syntax`
```

what I would like to display is pure text like this:

```
this is a test with markdown syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Markdown's [documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) states:

> Markdown provides backslash escapes for the following characters:
>
> ```
> \   backslash
> `   backtick
> *   asterisk
> _   underscore
> {}  curly braces
> []  square brackets
> ()  parentheses
> #   hash mark
> +   plus sign
> -   minus sign (hyphen)
> .   dot
> !   exclamation mark
> ```

You could write a template tag that strips out any of those characters as long as they are not preceded by a backslash escape (and only strips the backslash when they are).

However, Markdown doesn't always give those characters special meaning. For example:

> These (parenthesis) are ignored by Markdown.
>
> However [these](aren't) because they are part of a link.

In other words, some times you may want to strip the above list of characters, but sometimes you may not. In the end, you may find yourself re-implementing a markdown parser. Might as well use one that already exists and then simply pass the html through Django's built-in [striptags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags) filter. Or if you want to maintain block level tags and only strip a small selection of (inline) tags, the [removetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#removetags) filter may serve you better.

In either case, you don't need to write any Python code as you can just string a few existing filters together.

```
{{ value|markdown|striptags }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a template filter to remove those characters. For instance, convert the markdown to html and then apply striptags.